# Phonegap facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, cordova

I have installed the facebook API in phonegap but i have hard time making it work [see link](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect) .The index.html file in the exemple folder has a login button that once taped opens the native facebook application on my device requiring email and password. After having authenticated me, it takes me back succesfully to my app. 
Whenever i tap on the "getsession" button for exemple it shows me an alert saying "undefined". I want to know how to get the access token that is given right after the authentication process within my app and everything related to the session so i can perform other tasks?
Thank you

Comment: I would suggest to use the [PhoneGap Facebook plugin](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect) which handles all of your issues!!

Comment: You can always use this pre-made Xcodeproj: http://frario.it/phonegap-facebook-packag

Comment: Hi! i am not able to login when i am using this api....from GitHub link u have given...actually it shows me Error and telling please trying again....when i click ok than it goes to facebook home page but not opening login dialog....can u tell me what phonegap vesrsion are u using?